# Accessing Oracle Synonyms using Entity Framework 6 code first existing Database

Tags: c#, oracle11g, entity-framework-6, odac

I am working on C# application build based on Repository and Unit of work pattern. I have Synonyms coming from Oracle 11g database that I need to read data. I am not require to write back to this schema.

I have created Entity model 'Web_LookupsEntity' as I did with other Oracle Tables but getting following error; Specified cast is not valid

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

### Synonyms Entity

```
[Table("APPS_USER.LOOKUPS")]
public class Web_LookupsEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string RV_DOMAIN { get; set; }

    public int? LOOKUP_KEY { get; set; }

    public string DESCR { get; set; }

    public string EBS_CODE { get; set; }
}
```

### DbContext

```
 public class UCAS_WebDbContext : BaseContext<UCAS_WebDbContext>
{      
    public UCAS_WebDbContext() : base("EBSTest_AppUsers_DbContext")
    {}

    public DbSet<Web_EBS_SyncEntity> Web_EBS_Sync { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Web_LookupsEntity> Web_Lookups { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("APPS_USER");
    }
}
```

### Repository

```
  public class Web_LookupsRepository : GenericRepository<Web_LookupsEntity>
{
    public Web_LookupsRepository()
    { }

    public Web_LookupsRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        :base(dbContext)
    { }
}
```

### Unit of Work

```
 public class UCAS_WebSync_AdminTool_UOF : IDisposable
{
    private UCAS_WebDbContext _UCAS_WebDbContextObject = new UCAS_WebDbContext();

    protected Web_LookupsRepository _Web_LookupsRepository;

    public Web_LookupsRepository Web_LookupsRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._Web_LookupsRepository == null)
            {
                this._Web_LookupsRepository = new Web_LookupsRepository(_UCAS_WebDbContextObject);
            }

            return _Web_LookupsRepository;
        }
    }
  //.... remaining save context code...
```

### Encapsulation Function class

```
public partial class UCAS_Sync_Core
{

    public IList<Web_LookupsEntity> GetWeb_Web_Lookups()
    {
        IList<Web_LookupsEntity> _Web_Lookups = null;

        using (var _uof = new UCAS_WebSync_AdminTool_UOF())
        {
            _Web_Lookups = _uof.Web_LookupsRepository.GetAll().ToList();
        }

        return _Web_Lookups;
    }
}
```

### Calling Lookup Encapsulated method to get list of Lookups from synonyms

```
  UCAS_Sync_Core obj4 = new UCAS_Sync_Core();

  var xx7 = obj4.GetWeb_Web_Lookups();
```